# Timer to dispose a jFrame and fill a progress bar

Tags: java, swing, timer

I'm a beginner, i want to start a timer when i run my program (i.e when the parent jFrame shows up) and dispose the frame after 5 sec. And i want to start filling a dummy progress bar when the timer starts and fill it completely till the timer goes out.

Comment: this isnt a place where we write the code for you. this is a place where you get help once youve tried something and it doesnt work.

Comment: Hey, i have tried to do this but got loads of errors and then i got confused.

Comment: ok then, post your latest attempt

Comment: At least you can tell me the syntax.

Comment: I can't as i'm using my mobile phone.

Answer (score 5):

here's your code

```
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.awt.event.WindowEvent;
public class ClosingPanel extends JFrame{
private final Timer every50millis;

public ClosingPanel() {
    setTitle("this panel will self-destruct");
    setDefaultCloseOperation(DISPOSE_ON_CLOSE);
    final JProgressBar progressBar = new JProgressBar(SwingConstants.HORIZONTAL, 0, 100);
    add(progressBar);
    pack();
    every50millis = new Timer(50, new ActionListener() {
        private int count=0;
        @Override
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            count++;
            progressBar.setValue(count);
            if (count==100) {
                shutdown();
            }
        }
    });
    every50millis.start();
}

private void shutdown() {
    System.err.println("shutting down");
    every50millis.stop();
    WindowEvent closingEvent = new WindowEvent(ClosingPanel.this, WindowEvent.WINDOW_CLOSING);
    Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getSystemEventQueue().postEvent(closingEvent);
}

public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
    SwingUtilities.invokeAndWait(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            ClosingPanel panel = new ClosingPanel();
            panel.setVisible(true);
        }
    });
}
```

}

Comment: Can i use java.swing.timer instead of java.util.timer

Comment: you could, you should, and thats what the above code uses.

Comment: code updated with progress bar